# Can code in custom build variant override code in Main

Tags: android, gradle

I want to do extra job in `MyFragmentMock` only for build `VariantA`.

```
Main --
    java --
        ...
          view
            MyFragment (onFragmentReady())
VariantA[main] --
    java --
        ...
          view
            MyFragmentMock ((onFragmentReady()))
```

Because I don't want to touch the generic code in Main for a specific variant, my idea as below to call `onFragmentReady` in `MyFragmentMock` first and invoke the super method inside it then do the extra job. But `MyFragmentMock` is never invoked, it still go with the code in Main. Really newbie for Android, what should be the correct way to do this?

```
class MyFragmentMock : MyFragment() {
    override fun onFragmentReady() {
        super.onFragmentReady()
        // Do extra job here
    }
}
```

Comment: The classes needto have the same package and name. If you want to reuse part of the original MyFragement class you need to copy it or outsource the code-to-change to another class and then only have this other class in both variants.